Questions on Relative Forms and the de Rham Theorem in Geometry of Algebraic Curves, Vol. II
In Geometry of Algebraic Curves, Vol. II, by Arbarello, Cornalba, and Griffiths, they use the notation $\mathcal{A}^q_{X/Y}$ to define the sheaf of smooth relative $q$-forms for a smooth fibration $X \to Y$ and the notation $\mathcal{A}_X$ for the sheaf of differentiable functions on $X$.
On page 218, for
$$
\varphi : X \to \Delta
$$
a smooth proper morphism with compact Kähler manifold fibers and base a polydisc, they define the following:
On page 219:

Let us return to our original problem. Let $\eta$ be a $C^{\infty}$ closed relative
1-form on $X$, i.e., a section of forms $\mathcal{A}^q_{X/Δ}$ such that $d_{\varphi}\eta = 0$, where $d_{\varphi}$ stands for exterior differentiation along the fibers. Via the de Rham
theorem, the 1-form $\eta$ determines a section $[\eta]$ of $R^1\varphi_*\mathbb C\otimes \mathcal{A}_Δ$.

I have the following questions:

What does the definition of $\mathcal{A}^q_{X/Y}$ mean for a given fibration $f: X \to Y$? Specifically, what is a smooth relative 1-form on $X$?

What is the definition of $d_{\varphi}$ and what does exterior differentation along the fibers mean?

Which version of the de Rham theorem is being referenced here?

I understand that $R^1\varphi_*\mathbb{C}$ is the sheafification of the presheaf $U \mapsto H^1(\varphi^{-1}(U), \mathbb{C})$ for $U \subset \Delta$. So, is $R^1\varphi_*\mathbb{C} \otimes \mathcal{A}_{\Delta}$ the scalar extension viewed as a sheaf of modules?


I would really appreciate it if you could help me with this or recommend a book. I looked in Hartshorne and online, but I couldn't find the information I need.
